# Сохранение данных в приложении андроид

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных

Есть приложение с БД MySQL (пользователь из интерфейса приложения БД изменять не может, только читать данные из нее), кроме того, некоторые настройки приложения пишутся в файл.
Есть задача запоминать значение 0 или 1 для 100 параметров, пользователь будет сам менять их приложении и в итоге нужно будет их использовать.
Как это лучше реализовать? Прикрутить вторую БД? Или создать вторую таблицу в первой БД? Или можно это сделать на файлах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по всякому.

Если настройки не привязаны к устройству, а привязаны к аккаунту - то единственный способ - писать на сервер. У вас же БД на сервере? Однако, если у вас прямой доступ к БД на сервере из приложения (т.е. логин и пароль к БД в приложении находятся), а не скрыто это всё за API, то вам надо правильно настроить права доступа к БД, чтобы нельзя было случайно всё потереть.

Если настройки привязаны к устройству, то можно и просто в файл записать. На Android и iOS для этого есть стандартные возможности. На Android это SharedPreferences. Однако в этом случае данные будут теряться при смене девайса, очистки данных приложения или даже вручную при наличии root-доступа.

Как и что использовать - сложно сказать и всегда остаётся на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Хотя вроде даже вот похоже подойдет http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php

Comment: @ru38irk, да, похоже что именно SharedPreferences вам и нужны. Писать туда простые данные - просто.